# iTunes splitting albums containing songs from multiple different artists

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, ipod

[image]

As seen here, my iTunes is splitting my albums up. More specifically, albums that contain songs that have different artists names in the tags. Those "Avengers - Age of Ultron" albums are supposed to be one album.

Rocket Music player, as well as every other multimedia application I have used besides iTunes, all recognize and sort my albums correctly.

This is extremely frustrating and I was wondering if there was a way I could solve this without resorting to incorrectly tagging my music with the same artist as other songs in the album.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.  Select the affected songs and invoke “Get Info” (Cmd-I, I think). On the resulting panel, click the “This album is a compilation” box (something like that). Close the info panel and hopefully you’ll be in business.